# Map imported function to a variable

Tags: python, namespaces

I have some imported functions `from package import fizz, buzz` and I want to map them to a variable `func` from a string arg.

```
class Whatever(object):
    def __init__(self, func_name='fizz'):
        try:
            self.func = vars()[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            print "Bad func_name"
            raise
```

But `vars()` only captures the local namespace, and I don't want to allow access to `globals()`. Any ideas? Or should I just go with if-else logic?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: Why don't you pass the function *directly* to the initializer: `def __init__(self, func=fizz)`

Comment: But basically, if you want to access some global name outside the global scope using a string, then you sort of *have* to use `globals`, or even worse, something like `exec` or `eval`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check out `exec` and `eval`.
Also thinking I could just create a class attr dict that maps the strings to the imported functions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not passing the function directly b/c I don't have the caller import the functions, but rather they are imported where the class is defined. Are you suggesting this is bad (or nonpythonic)?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why are `exec` and `eval` evil?

Comment: Why don't you just create *your own namespace* using either `SimpleNamespace` or a `dict` even and make it a class-level variable or something and then access it from there.

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain The valid use-cases are limited (although they can be very powerful). But [`eval` and `exec` can be dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) if you don't trust the source, e.g. `eval('''__import__('os').system('echo "all your base are belong to us"') ''')`. Mostly though, in this case, it is major code smell.

Comment: And justimagine if I do something more nefarous than `echo "all your base are belong to us"`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a white list... or in this case, a "white dict"

```
class Whatever(object):

    allowed = { 'fizz':fizz, 'buzz':buz }

    def __init__(self, func_name='fizz'):
        try:
            self.func = self.allowed[func_name]
        except KeyError:
            print "Bad func_name"
            raise
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I mentioned in the comments above as a decent alternative.